# Bootstrap tab modal buggy

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-4-beta

I have a 2 tab in my modal `Team` and `Personal`. When the modal is opened the `Team` tab will be active and when i select on `Personal` it displays everything properly but when i want to toggle back to `Team` tab it does not displays the content in my `Team` tab. Any help would be appreciated thank you

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
        <div class="modal-content">

            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
                <h2 class="modal-title">Create Project</h2>
            </div>

            <!--TABS-->
            <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="pills-tab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item ">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="pills-team-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-team"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-team" aria-selected="true">Team</a>
                </li>

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="pills-personal-tab" data-toggle="pill" href="#pills-personal"
                        role="tab" aria-controls="pills-personal" aria-selected="false">Personal</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

            <!--BODY-->
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="tab-content">
                    <!--START TEAM TAB-->
                    <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="pills-team" role="tabpanel">
                        <p>team tabs</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--END TEAM TAB-->

                    <!--START PERSONAL TAB-->
                    <div class="tab-pane fade" id="pills-personal" role="tabpanel">
                        <p>personal tab</p>
                    </div>
                    <!--END PERSONAL TAB-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I just tested. Everything seems to work perfectly. Btw I'm sure you have id for the root div of modal. `<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="someId" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel"
    aria-hidden="true">`

Comment: @abdulla_malik do i need an id? what is it for?... I'm using bootstrap 4 alpha 6 is that why its not working? but previously it was working perfectly fine

Comment: Yes, you need Id for selecting the modal.

Comment: Check getbootstap.com/JavaScript modal